# How do I generate an X11 geometry string using Xlib?

Tags: c, linux, unix, x11, xlib

I know you can parse them using XParseGeometry, but I also need to generate them.
Are there any built in or external functions that could do this for me?

I tried to make my own function that does this, but it was ridiculously buggy.

Comment: You can use `sprintf`

Comment: I know I can use that for string generation, but I have no idea how to actually encode the string (you know, the plus and minus signs between the values)

Comment: Just put those in the format string.  You should [edit] your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
char buf[42];
sprintf(buf, "%dx%d+%d+%d", width, height, x, y);
```